# Transformations of the complex plane

Tags: geometry, transformation

I was reading my text and just had some questions about transformations:

(1) Are all line preserving transformations linear transformations? Why?

I want to say yes... but I feel like the answer is no, haha.

(2) Are all linear transformations angle preserving transformations?

(3) Define a transformation $t: z \mapsto t(z)$ that is not a Möbius transformation.

Is that anything that is not one-to-one? So can I just define $z \mapsto\lvert z\rvert$?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "line preserving" but yes, every linear fractional transformation preserves angles (each is "conformal") and $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is a good example of a smooth automorphism of the Riemann sphere that isnt a linear fractional transformation.

Comment: Hint: for (1) consider translations. For (2) the answer depends on your underlying space, which seems to be $\mathbb C$ not $\mathbb R^2$ in your case.

Comment: For (1), for translations, they do preserve lines and are linear transformations, no? So I feel like the answer is yes then, but is that enough concrete enough of a justification?

For (2), I think linear transformations are not all angle preserving, we need orthogonal transformations to ensure they are angle preserving?

And I understand (3). I can just define some map where (ad - bc = 0) in the default formula for the Mobius Transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If by "line-preserving" you mean there is some line $L=\left\{z_0+tz_1|t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ such that $f(L)=L$, then the answer is no.  Consider the line $\left\{t|t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ and the map $f:z\mapsto z+1$.  This is clearly not linear over $\mathbb{C}$, but does preserve a line.

(2) No.  Consider the linear map $f:z\mapsto 0$.  This pretty clearly doesn't preserve angles, if you even try to define the "angle" between $0$ and itself.

(3) Is this different than (2)?  Yes, $f:z\mapsto \left|z\right|$ would work, if you call that a transformation (I guess it depends on your definition of a "transformation").

Sorry if this is to basic.  Hope it helps.